# Spring Boot @SpringBootTest Annotation: Inconsistent property loading when tests run in submodule vs. whole package

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test, spring-boot-test

I have a Spring Boot application that is divided into several submodules. Each submodule contains tests with the `@SpringBootTest` annotation. Each test extends the same parent class that also has this annotation.

Below the simplified version of the parent class:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {
    IntegrationTestsApp.class }, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, properties = {
            "security.basic.enabled = false" })
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-test.properties")

public class BaseIntegrationTest {

// ...

}
```

And here, an example of the test within a given submodule.

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {
    IntegrationTestsApp.class }, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT, properties = {
    "app.server.address = 127.0.0.1" })
public class ServiceATest extends BaseIntegrationTest {

@Autowired
private ServiceA service;


@Test
void test() {
    System.out.println(getClass().getName()+" AppContextService.getContext().getEnvironment().getProperty(\"app.server.address\") = " 
    + AppContextService.getContext().getEnvironment().getProperty("app.server.address"));
    System.out.println("PropsResolver.resolve(${app.server.address}) = " + new PropsResolver().resolve("${app.server.address}"));
    System.out.println("PropsResolver.resolve(${app.server.address:localhost}) = " + new PropsResolver().resolve("${app.server.address:localhost}"));  
    // assertions

}
}
```

What the test assesses is not relevant. The problem I am dealing with is related to the mechanism of loading properties defined in the `@SpringBootTest` annotation, which is unclear to me. When I run the test in IDE separately, the `System.out.println` statements show the value which is defined in the annotation, i.e.:`127.0.0.1`. When I run the test in its own submodule ("Run Tests in submoduleX"), then the value is also `127.0.0.1`. However, when I run the test from the entire package (where I have submoduleX, submoduleY, and submoduleZ), then the value is `localhost`.

What's even more interesting, another test from the same package, let's say ServiceBTest, loads properties according to the `properties` passed in the annotation.
In other words, I have TestA and TestB in the submoduleX, and when I run all tests in the module, TestA prints "127...", and TestB "localhost".

My questions:

1. If Spring creates one context for each submodule, then where does the difference in the property value passed in the annotation come from?
2. Why, even within the same package, some tests load the value provided by the annotation, while others cannot access it and take the default value?

---

Some extra information after the discussion with M. Deinum:

1. Both TestA and TestB are in the same submodule, have the same annotation (`@SpringBootTest`) with the same content, i.e.: `@SpringBootTest(classes = { IntegrationTestsApp.class }, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT, properties = { "app.server.address = 127.0.0.1" })`, and both extend the same parent class that was presented before.
2. When I put `app.server.address = 127.0.0.1` to the `application-test.properties`, the test displays the provided value even if all tests in the module are run at once.

M. Deinum's suggestion was that there might be a clash between the `@SpringBootTest` annotations, as there are two instead of one. Is it possible that this is the case and how could I investigate this further?

---

**Further investigation**

My further investigation confirmed that more than one `ApplicationContext` is created. What's interesting is that a specific `ApplicationContext` can be used in different submodules. The following table schematically represents the observed scenario:

| Class | Package | Context |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | A | Context 1 |
| B | A | Context 2 |
| C | A | Context 3 |
| D | B | Context 1 |
| E | C | Context 3 |

After M. Deinum wrote that having double `@SpringBootTest` may cause confusion, I thought that a new context is created when the duplication is spotted. However, this is not the case. The number of tests with "double" `@SpringBootTest` is less than the number of created contexts.

If we put `app.server.address` in the application-test.properties, we will always arrive at the value 127.0.0.1. Nonetheless, we still have numerous contexts.

Comment: 1. It doesn't. It loads and caches a context based on the permuations of the `@SpringBootTest`, `@MockBean`, registered `TestContextListeners` and more. If they match it will reuse. 2. See 1 becuase there are some differences in the context and thus another one is used. Also if you run multiple tests it will generate 1 massive classpath and the first `application-test.properties` etc. will be loaded not all of them.

Comment: I have some further questions: 
1. What steps would you take to identify the difference in contexts between two tests in a given package, in order to deterministically determine their behavior?
2. If we have only one `application-test.properties`, won't we end up with only one regardless of how many tests inherit from `BaseIntegrationTest`?

Comment: And also: Even if, due to various parameter configurations that you mentioned, the context is not loaded from the cache, I do not understand why the test is not able to read the property defined in the annotation. What is the impact of reading the context from the cache or not (creating it anew) on the ability to read properties defined in the annotation?

Comment: Do you only have 1 properties file. To me it sounds like you have 1 in each sub module and when running just one of those will be picked. What is being read depends also on what is loaded, although `@TestPropertySource` should take precedence. That being said without knowning what is loaded and what is further in play (autoconfigurations for test etc. etc) this will be hard to answer.

Comment: There is only one file named `application-test.properties`, and it is located in the module where the parent class is defined. `@TestPropertySource` seems to have higher precedence than properties defined in `@SpringBootTest` because adding the `app.server.address` to the `application-test.properties` changed the output to `127.0.0.1` when tests are run all at once. It is however still unclear to me what causes this strange behaviour. TestA and TestB are both in Submodule X, extend the same class, have same annotations, and same props defined in the annotation.

Comment: `@TestPropertySource` always has precedence as that is considered the most local to the test. Another thing that is weird is the multiple `@SpringBootTest` annotations, I suspect they interfere with each other.

Comment: @M.Deinum I added some details about my further investigation.

Comment: As stated different per mutations of settings, test execution listeners, configurations being detected etc. etc. (there is a long list actually) all lead to different application contexts being loaded. For a list of things see https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management-caching

Comment: Theoretically, yes. I have three different annotation constellations. When you turn on context logging, Spring will report on three different contexts: A, B, and C. What is extremely perplexing is that when you print out the hashcode of the current context in a given test and do it for all tests, you will get a total of five different contexts instead of three. A, B, and C are present, but you also have D and E, and it does not seem to follow any reasonable pattern.

Comment: I'm not sure if hashcode the best way to determine if they are the same, there might be some proxying going on, especially on restoring. You are probably better of comparing the application context ids. However as stated before depending on what is in use a new context is created (see the list) and depending how your tests are written this might differ as well.